# what is the equivalent operation in MongoDB for Minus set operation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB collections:

```
feb = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591df31cbbcd51d52653553c"),
    "patientId" : 2,
    "fullName" : "Lopez , Julia",
    "EVOLUCIÓN" : "Medicada"
}, ...]



may = [
    {"_id" : ObjectId("59231f3ab36e83e3db6e03f8"),
    "patientId" : 4,
    "fullName" : "Martinez , Carolina",
    "EVOLUCIÓN" : "15/08/97 : MEDICADA CON DERRUMAL A TERMINAR, TOMANIL GEL, ADAXIL AMP, ZOCOR 5, RENITEC 5, CERVILANE, Y AMLOC 5."
}, ...]
```

**I need to get the projection of feb - may over fullName with a MongoDB query**.
In SQL would be:

```
SELECT fullName
FROM feb
MINUS
SELECT fullName
FROM may;
```

Comment: Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do queries across multiple collections at once in `MongoDB`. You will have to emulate the `MINUS` with two separated queries at application level:

First, you get the names in May:

```
namesInMay = db.may.distinct("fullName");
```

Then, you do the same with February, but filtering out those that are also in `namesInMay` using the [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator:

```
db.feb.distinct("fullName", { "fullName": { $nin: namesInMay }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
db.address.aggregate([
{
  $replaceRoot: { 
    newRoot: { _id: "$_id", source: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}}
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "address1", 
    localField: "_id", 
    foreignField: "_id",  
    as: "target"
  }
},
{
  $replaceRoot: { 
    newRoot: { _id: "$_id", source: "$source", target : {$objectToArray: { $first : "$target"}}}
  }
},
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: { _id: "$_id", source: { $setDifference: ["$source","$target"]}, target: { $setDifference: ["$target","$source"]}}
  }
}
]);
```

This will work if the collections are in the same database, and have the same "_id"'s. It could easily be modified to join on other critera.

The output looks something like this..

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023970"), "source" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : "" }, { "k" : "phone", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : null }, { "k" : "phone", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023971"), "source" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : "" }, { "k" : "phone", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : null }, { "k" : "phone", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023972"), "source" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023973"), "source" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "postal_code", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023974"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023975"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023976"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023977"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023978"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023979"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397a"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397b"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397c"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397d"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397e"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f02397f"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023980"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023981"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023982"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f8dc3abc6ff46000f023983"), "source" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : "" } ], "target" : [ { "k" : "address2", "v" : null } ] }
Type "it" for more
```